# Compostion of tempered distribution and linear map.

Tags: functional-analysis, normal-distribution, linear-transformations

While solving a particular problem about composition of tempered distributions and an affine transformation, I ended up having to prove the following for $u\in\mathscr{S}'$ and a linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$: $$u(\hat{\phi}\circ L^{-1}) = |\det L| u(\widehat{\phi\circ L^t)}$$

But I am stuck from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $|\det(L)| \neq 0$, then $L\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\phi \in \mathscr{S}$ and define $z(x)=L^tx$. Use the transformation rule to obtain
$$
\widehat{(\phi \circ L^t)}(k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} {e^{-ik \cdot x}\phi(L^tx)}dx
= \frac{1}{|\det T|}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} {e^{-ik \cdot L^{-t}z(x)}\phi(z(x)) |\det T|} dx
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{|\det T|}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} {e^{-ik \cdot L^{-t}z}\phi(z)} dx
= \frac{1}{|\det T|}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} {e^{-iL^{-1}k \cdot z}\phi(z)} dx
= \frac{1}{|\det T|}\hat{\phi}(L^{-1}k)
$$
Since $u \in \mathscr{S}'$ is linear
$$
u(\hat{\phi}\circ L^{-1}) = |\det L|u(\widehat{\phi\circ L^t)}
$$
which is the stement.